# Will Cron Job Start Today?

Tags: cron

Lets say I schedule a cron job to run every 3 days:

```
0 22 */3 * *
```

Will it start tonight at 10pm or in three days at 10pm?

Comment: This should actually be asked on superuser. The third element is the day of month. Since today is the 29th of March the job won't run today.

Comment: You have chosen the wrong answer because two independent cron testing tools have shown that the script does not run tomorrow but on the 31st - unless you are skipping a day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third element is the day of month. Since today is the 29th of March the job won't run today. The next time it will be run is the 31st of March.

The /3 notation performs a modulo operation on the day of month -1. So all the commenters are totally right */3 will run on 1, 4, 7, etc. Every third day after the first day of the week.

Comment: Ok so it will start tomorrow?

Comment: Correct! It will run tomorrow!

Comment: I question the validity of this answer, unless it is the 31st tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this crontab testing tool](http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=0%2022%20*%2F3%20*%20*&iterations=10&test=Test) the next 10 runs will be as follows:

```
2016-03-31 22:00:00
2016-04-01 22:00:00
2016-04-04 22:00:00
2016-04-07 22:00:00
2016-04-10 22:00:00
2016-04-13 22:00:00
2016-04-16 22:00:00
2016-04-19 22:00:00
2016-04-22 22:00:00
2016-04-25 22:00:00
```

Another crontab tester - [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru/#0_22_*/3_*_*) - tells me that the script will run:

> At 22:00 on the 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28 and 31st of every
>   month.